# Proof that a continuous function from the unit ball to itself without fixed points implies existence of retract from unit ball to unit sphere

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Assume $f:B_{1}\to B_{1}$
  (where $B_{1}$
  is the closed unit-ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
 ) is a continuous function that has no fixed points I need to construct a function $g:B_{1}\to B_{1}$  which is a retract, that is continuous and $g|_{\partial B_{1}}=\mbox{Id}$
 . This is what I tried, define $a:B_{1}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$
  such that $a\left(x\right)$
  is the unique solution of $\left\Vert x-a\left(x\right)\cdot\left(f\left(x\right)-x\right)\right\Vert =1
 .$
  and define $g$
  by $g\left(x\right)=x-a\left(x\right)\cdot\left(f\left(x\right)-x\right)$.

For any $\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1$
  we get $a\left(x\right)=0$
  and thus $g\left(x\right)=x$
  meaning $g|_{\partial B_{1}}=\mbox{Id}$
  like we want. Now if $a$
  was continuous then $g$
  would immediately be continuous and I would have what I need. Problem is I'm not sure how to show $a$
  is continuous... Help would be appreciated

Comment: Your $a(x)$ is not defined where $f(x)=0$.  I think the usual definition is $\|x+a(x)(f(x)-x)\|=1$.

Comment: Oh that's a good point, I didn't notice that. I will correct the question. Still no idea how to show $a$ is continuous though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use the definition
$$\|x+a(x)(f(x)-x)\|=1$$
Then
$$(x+a(x)(f(x)-x),x+a(x)(f(x)-x))=1$$
so
$$\|x\|^2+2a(x)(x,f(x)-x)+a(x)^2\|f(x)-x\|^2=1$$
Thus
$$a(x)=\frac{-2(x,f(x)-x)\pm\sqrt{4(x,f(x)-x)^2+4(1-\|x\|^2)\|f(x)-x\|^2}}{2\|f(x)-x\|^2}$$
and if we take the positive root we get
$$a(x)=\frac{-2(x,f(x)-x)+\sqrt{4(x,f(x)-x)^2+4(1-\|x\|^2)\|f(x)-x\|^2}}{2\|f(x)-x\|^2}$$
which is guaranteed to be nonnegative and continuous.

Comment: Very nice, thanks :)

Comment: @Serpahimz You're welcome.